How do zkSync Blocks Work?
I am reading the zkSync documentation and seeing "L1 Batches" and "L1 Rollup Blocks." Are they the same thing?
When a batch of transactions is sent to Ethereum as an L1 batch, how is it included in the L1 block? My assumption would be that an L1 batch is added in the same way that a transaction on the L1 is usually added rather than an L1 batch occupying an entire block on the L1.

Your assumption is correct!
An L1 batch is added is posted to Ethereum with an Ethereum transaction, and does not occupy an entire block on the L1.
L2Beat keeps an updated list of zkSync's L1 contracts. You can check those addresses on Etherscan to see the exact transactions that are being posted. Here's a recent example of commiting a batch (notice the blobs)
